# How to draw a line along the bounding box of a text segment?

Tags: svg, gnuplot, svg-filters

Gnuplot supports a "boxed text" property that draws a box with optional fill around a text label.  Since gnuplot knows essentially nothing about fonts, it relies on device-specific code to generate the appropriate box.  This is implemented for most gnuplot output devices, but I cannot figure out how to support this for svg output.  In particular I know how to use a filter to generate a solid-fill box around the text (see example below), but I do not know how to draw a line around that same box.

Here is a fragment of the svg output by gnuplot, and screenshots of the resulting rendered svg image and the desired result output by a different gnuplot output device.

Note that I am ***not*** asking how to obtain and modify the bounding box in javascript. I am asking for generation of a native svg document.

```
<svg 
 width="600" height="480"
 viewBox="0 0 600 480"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="480" fill="none"/>
<defs>

        <filter id='textbox' filterUnits='objectBoundingBox' x='0' y='0' height='1' width='1'>
          <feFlood flood-color='cyan' flood-opacity='1' result='bgnd'/>
          <feComposite in='SourceGraphic' in2='bgnd' operator='atop'/>
        </filter>
</defs>

<g id="textbox 1">
        <g transform="translate(297.9,244.6)" stroke="none" fill="black" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.00"  text-anchor="start" style='filter:url(#textbox)'>
                <text><tspan font-family="Arial" >A two-line label</tspan>
                      <tspan x="0" dy="12" font-family="Arial" > in a box </tspan></text>
        </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image: svg output]
[image: png output]

**Update:**

The three answers proposed so far are based on using the filter+fill operations essentially to place a slightly larger rectangle around a slightly smaller rectangle.  This is not the same as drawing a line.  It does not scale easily, and the resulting appearance does not match that of other lines in the same figure. I really want some way to issue a "stroke" rather than a "fill" operation for the group or text bounding box. This would allow matching the join, thickness, and other properties of other lines in the figure.

The bounding box coordinates are clearly implicit in the svg context, both because they are used by the filter+fill and because they can be queried by javascript.  Is it really the case that they cannot be used for "stroke"?

Comment: In javascript you can use the ´.getBBox()´ method to get the position (x,y) and the size (width, height) of the bounding box and you can use all this to draw a rect around the text.

Comment: Yes, but the question is explicitly not about javascript and not about DOM methods.  The goal is to generate a static svg document, say for publication or inclusion in a word-processing document.

Comment: @Ethan can you include your gnuplot code. I've never used gnuplot before, but in version 5.2 of gnuplot the textbox has a style to set a border. Maybe that's what you could use. It's described on page 175 of the [gnuplot 5.2 manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf)

Comment: Also is your intention to use gnuplot to create an svg with a line around it or to write the code that goes into gnuplot itself so that it can support the feature? I'm starting to think you mean the latter from rereading your statements, but I wrote my previous comment as if you intended the former.

Comment: @John.  I was the one who added gnuplot support for text boxes, but I was not able to do it for all terminals.  Of the terminal types that don't yet support it, IMHO SVG is the most important, followed by EMF.

Answer (score 1):

Without being a SVG specialist, I played with Inkscape and your SVG. It looks like there is no easy frame command (at least I haven't found), but some Gaussian blur filter effects you can apply to the textbox. I assume you can rename `id="filter1780"` to something else.

I also changed the line to get some margin around the text:

`<filter id='textbox' filterUnits='objectBoundingBox' x='-0.1' y='-0.1' height='1.2' width='1.2'>`

If you adapt the numbers you might end up with a sharp frame around your text.
No guarantee that this is valid SVG, and it looks like a ugly and lengthy workaround, but at least it looks like what you are aiming for.

**SVG-code:**

```
<svg 
 width="600" height="480"
 viewBox="0 0 600 480"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="480" fill="none"/>
<defs>

    <filter id='textbox' filterUnits='objectBoundingBox' x='-0.1' y='-0.1' height='1.2' width='1.2'>
      <feFlood flood-color='cyan' flood-opacity='1' result='bgnd'/>
      <feComposite in='SourceGraphic' in2='bgnd' operator='atop'/>
    </filter>

    <filter id="filter1780" x="-.2" y="-.2" width="1.4" height="1.4" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="blur1" stdDeviation="0.33"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="blur1" operator="out" result="composite1"/>
      <feColorMatrix result="colormatrix1" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 100 -0 "/>
      <feGaussianBlur result="blur2" stdDeviation="0.01"/>
      <feComposite in="blur2" in2="blur2" result="composite2"/>
      <feColorMatrix result="colormatrix2" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 100 -0 "/>
      <feGaussianBlur result="blur3" stdDeviation="0.01"/>
      <feColorMatrix result="colormatrix3" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 5 -1 "/>
      <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="colormatrix3" k2="1" operator="in" result="composite3"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="colormatrix3" operator="out" result="composite4"/>
      <feComposite in="composite4" in2="composite3" k2="1" k3="1" operator="arithmetic" result="composite5"/>
    </filter>

</defs>

<g id="textbox 1">
    <g filter="url(#filter1780)">
        <g transform="translate(297.9,244.6)" stroke="none" fill="black" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.00"  text-anchor="start" style='filter:url(#textbox)'>
            <text><tspan font-family="Arial" >A two-line label</tspan>
                  <tspan x="0" dy="12" font-family="Arial" > in a box </tspan></text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler solution:

```html
<svg 
 width="600" height="480"
 viewBox="0 0 600 480"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="480" fill="none"/>
<defs>

        <filter id='textbox' filterUnits='objectBoundingBox' x='-0.1' y='-0.1' height='1.2' width='1.2'>
          <feFlood flood-color='red' flood-opacity='1' result='fg'/>
          <feFlood flood-color='cyan' flood-opacity='1' result='bgnd'/>
          <feOffset in="bgnd" dx="2" dy="2" result="disp1" />
          <feOffset in="bgnd" dx="-2" dy="-2" result="disp2" />
          <feComposite in='disp2' in2='disp1' operator='in' result="crop" />
          <feComposite in='crop' in2='fg' operator='atop' result="op1" />
          <feComposite in='SourceGraphic' in2='op1' operator='atop' result="op2" />
        </filter>
</defs>

<g id="textbox 1">
        <g transform="translate(297.9,244.6)" stroke="none" fill="black" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.00"  text-anchor="start" style='filter:url(#textbox)'>
                <text><tspan font-family="Arial" >A two-line label</tspan>
                      <tspan x="0" dy="12" font-family="Arial" > in a box </tspan></text>
        </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the range of the text label sizes. This puts a filter adding a larger background on the parent g using the filter region dimensions - but these are relative to the label size - so it won't work well for all ratios of width to height.

```html
<svg 
 width="600" height="480"
 viewBox="0 0 600 480"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="480" fill="none"/>
<defs>
  
          <filter id='outline' filterUnits='objectBoundingBox' x='-.02' y='-0.06' height='1.12' width='1.04'>
          <feFlood flood-color='black' flood-opacity='1' result='bgnd'/>
          <feComposite in='SourceGraphic' in2='bgnd' operator='over'/>
        </filter>

        <filter id='textbox' filterUnits='objectBoundingBox' x='0' y='0' height='1' width='1'>
          <feFlood flood-color='cyan' flood-opacity='1' result='bgnd'/>
          <feComposite in='SourceGraphic' in2='bgnd' operator='atop'/>
        </filter>
</defs>

<g id="textbox 1" filter="url(#outline)">
        <g transform="translate(297.9,244.6)" stroke="none" fill="black" font-family="Arial" font-size="12.00"  text-anchor="start" style='filter:url(#textbox)'>
                <text><tspan font-family="Arial" >A two-line label</tspan>
                      <tspan x="0" dy="12" font-family="Arial" > in a box </tspan></text>
        </g>
</g>
</svg>
```